# is there a way to use where like query in laravel with variable from GET method?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

i want to filter with like in laravel project and paginate with laravel paginate, i try this code

```
$search = $request->get('query');  
$products= DB::table('products')
           ->where('nama_produk', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%') 
           ->paginate(6);
```

when use this code nothing error but it return all of data in my database table and not filtered.

if i use this code

```
$search = $request->get('query');  
$products= DB::table('products')
           ->where('nama_produk', 'LIKE', '%test%') 
           ->paginate(6);
```

it Worked :( 
can someone help me to solve this problem ?

Comment: I try your code. It works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is my search controller :

```
public function search(Request $request){
  $query = $request->query;
  $search = Post::where('post_title', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->orWhere('post_body', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->orWhere('post_tags', 'LIKE', "%$query%")->orderBy('created_at')->paginate(10);
  return view('front.search', ['posts'=> $search, 'query'=> $query]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i got 

Object of class Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag could not be converted to string

Comment: change `$query = $request->query;` to `$request->input('query');` or `$request->get('query')` ...whats the output now?

Comment: @RizkyPermanaPutra, then your search query is same like all selected fields.